# Can you use the word "bearing" to mean causing?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Can you use the word "bearing" to mean when smething causes something?

For example, I'm trying to write a poem thing and I'm using the sentence "the bleak bearing blanket of fog" to describe how a blanket of fog above a piece of land causes it to be bleak.

If "bearing" doesn't make sense here, what could I use instead?

Edit:

Nevermind, I'll just take the bearing part out. It just had to rhyme with peak, here's a bigger extract:

> ...the tallest mountain, and only it's peak could puncture the bleak [bearing] blanket of fog above.

So yeah, I'll just take the *bearing* part out, thanks though.

Comment: Here, *bearing* implies the fog is *carrying* the bleakness, not *causing* it.

Comment: Though I thought bearing could mean related to, right? Is it incorrect in this regard too?

Comment: Not quite; it's the phrasal verb *bearing on* that means *related to*. But it wouldn't fit in your sentence. But as @Dan says, *bleak bearing blanket of fog* works fine here, even if it doesn't quite mean *causing*.

Comment: Yes, @PeterShor is correct, it's the phrase *bearing on* which means *related to* (and it's worth pointing out that phrase doesn't mean *causing*, either; in fact, it's used specifically when we want to draw a connection *without* ascribing a causal relation).

Comment: "...the fog, bearing bleakness" would work.

Comment: "bleakening" is a great verb. It is in use, though you probably won't find it in an "official" dictionary.

Comment: The bleak blanket of fog bearing down over the land.

Comment: If you love alliteration, try: "...the tallest mountain, and only it's peak could be seen, braving the bleak brooding blanket of fog blighting its beauty."

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear whether you particularly want the alliteration of the repeated 'b' sound. An alternative might be "[a land covered by] the blanketing bleakness of fog". I appreciate that in this instance it is the fog that is described as "bleak" but it seems, at least to me, to convey a similar idea.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

*"the blanket of fog **turns** the sight [from the land] to bleakness"*

*"the blanket of fog **bears down on** the land, turning it to bleakness"*

where

**bear down on** or **bear down upon** = proceed toward, especially impressively, awesomely, or forcibly